# ec2 VPC: route from private subnet to vpn subnet on vpc peer

Tags: amazon-ec2, pptp, amazon-vpc

I have an Amazon EC2 VPC with private IP address range `172.28.0.0/16`. Two instances are in the VPC: `alpha (172.28.1.13)` and `bravo (172.28.1.99)`. The `alpha` instance is running a `pptp` server with `localip 192.168.13.1` and `remoteip 192.168.13.2-250`.

I want `bravo (172.28.1.99)` to ping clients on the the `alpha (172.28.1.13)` pptp subnet, `192.168.13.0/24`. For example if I connect to the VPN on my laptop, and my IP is `192.168.13.2`, then `bravo (172.28.1.99)` should be able to ping me.

This seems like a job for VPC routing tables. So I added an entry to the ec2 routing table: destination `192.168.13.0/24` via instance-id of `alpha`. Traceroute to `192.168.13.2` from `bravo` appears to go nowhere.

I am unable to ping `192.168.13.2` from `172.28.1.99`.

Sanity checks: all security groups open to world... can ping between bravo and alpha via `172.28.1.13` and `172.28.1.99`.

Is there an additional step I need to take after adding an entry to the VPC routing table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 (VPC) instances have an IP source/destination check enabled on their interfaces by default.  For NAT instances, as well as configurations like the one you describe, this needs to be disabled for traffic to flow.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck

Comment: Thank you.  Disabling that on both instances allows me to ping `196.168.13.1` (i.e., the EC2 server running the VPN). However, I still cannot ping `192.168.13.2` (the VPN client IP). From the VPN server instance, I was able to ping it after running `sudo ip route add 192.168.13.0/24 dev ppp0`. However I cannot ping it from the other EC2 instance.

Comment: Or -- I suspect -- the client can't reply?  The client needs a static route to the 172.28.0.0/16 network over the tunnel, or needs to use the tunnel as its default gateway.